# Jquery or javascript to add one line break <br /> after x amount of characters in a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a way to insert a `<br />` after only the first 4 or 5 characters in a `<div>`.

Example:
`<div id="wine-name">`2008 Cabernet Sauvignon`</div>`

To display like:
**2008

Cabernet Sauvignon**

Not sure which would be easier javascript or jQuery. The site is already using jQuery.

Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, and it makes normally things easier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are certain that you always want to insert the break after the fourth character, you can do this:

```
var html = $("#wine-name").html();
html = html.substring(0, 4) + "<br>" + html.substring(4);
$("#wine-name").html(html);
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UJgAa/).

If you want it to instead break after the first word (delimited by spaces), you can do this instead:

```
var html = $("#wine-name").html().split(" ");
html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
$("#wine-name").html(html);
```

You can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UJgAa/2/).

EDITed for your comment:

```
$(".wine-name").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UJgAa/3/).

Comment: Thanks, either of these work great provided there is only 1 div.  In my case, a set of wines get populated in a series of li's and although each wine has a div id that = "wine-name", this only affects the first wine in the list. Strange.

Comment: @Rod, you cannot have two elements with the same id. You are wanting a class. Look at my edited post to see what I mean.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I added a <span class="wine-name"> and it worked perfectly. You rock, thanks!

Comment: @M.Woodard I'm not sure what you mean. This works for any number of words. Are you asking how to break after the second word instead of the first?

Comment: @PeterOlson - Yes, 2 words rather than 1

Comment: @MatthewWoodard Just do `html = html.slice(0,2).join("") + "<br>" + html.slice(2).join("")`

Answer (score 0):

The code in JavaScript would look something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('wine-name');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.substring(0, element.innerHTML.indexOf(' ')) + '<br />' + element.innerHTML.substring(element.innerHTML.indexOf(' '), element.innerHtml.length);
```

It's probably better to go with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

> Both the above answers have not considered the fact that the use case might include sentences where the break should be included at the nearest space prior to required limit .
> i.e. Above methods will break the words at specified index. But in most cases that is not the most suitable solution. Here is my take on this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book";
   //var str = "LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypeset tingindustry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimensdfdfdfdfsdsds book";
  var originalStr = str;
  str = splitString(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}
function splitString(str)
{
    var originalStr = str;
      var charLimit = 50;
      var slicedStringList = [];
      var flag = 1;
      while(flag)
      {
        if(str.length <=50)
        {
          slicedStringList.push(str);
          flag=0;
        }
        else
        {
          var tempChar = str[charLimit]
          if(tempChar == ' ' ||tempChar == '\n' ||tempChar == '\r')
          {
            slicedStringList.push(str.substring(0,charLimit));
            str = str.substring(charLimit+1,originalStr.length);
          }
          else
          {
            var tempStr = str.substring(0,charLimit);
            var nearestSpace = tempStr.lastIndexOf(" ");
            if(nearestSpace>-1)
            {
              slicedStringList.push(str.substring(0,nearestSpace));
              str = str.substring(nearestSpace+1,originalStr.length);
            }
            else
            {
              slicedStringList.push(tempStr);
              str = str.substring(charLimit+1,originalStr.length);
            }
          }
        }
         
      }
      var newString = slicedStringList.join("<br>");
      return newString;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But its probably better to go with css instead.(more subtle)