# Insert element after several characters

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery or javascript to add one line break <br /> after x amount of characters in a <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068653/jquery-or-javascript-to-add-one-line-break-br-after-x-amount-of-characters-i)

I'd like to insert a `br` tag five characters into the content of the element. For example, from this:

```
<p>qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm</p>
```

To this:

```
<p>qwert<br />yuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm</p>
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068653/jquery-or-javascript-to-add-one-line-break-br-after-x-amount-of-characters-i

Comment: the problem is i want to add <br> because i work with languange like japan, if in English we have sentence or word but in japan no space between word or sentence that why i want to add something like <br>

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the innerHTML with this function (Fires on document.ready()):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').html($('p').html().substring(0,5)+'<br/>'+$('p').html().substring(5));
}
);
```

You can try it on jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KwpGr/1/

Comment: can i replace <br/> with this <!--read more-->

Comment: Why not... Shouldn't be a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/KwpGr/2/ - You can see the substition with WebInspector (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox)

Comment: ok thanks, last question if i want to put <br/> at last string, how? <p>qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm<br /></p>

Comment: `$('p').html($('p').html()+'<br/>');` - Please do yourself a favour and try to understand what happens...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an implicit callback on `$.html()`:

```
/* Be sure to specify which paragraph this applies to */
$("p").html(function(i,v){
  return v.replace( /^([\w]{5})/, "$1<br/>" );
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/orovom/2/edit